# Showing dropdown menu in bootstrap V3.0.3 on the top of the accordion

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion, dropdown

I have Accordion and I created a dropdown menu inside it.

The dropdown appears under the Accordion in the last item.

[image: Dropdown menu]

This is the code of dropdown:

```
<div class="dropdown ">
<a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
   data-target="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu download-dropdown pull-left" role="menu">
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#">Original data</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#">Original data</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

How can I make it appears on the top of accordion?

Thank in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/p0cxsfbx/1/

Comment: can you show your css

Comment: I didn't make override for the classes of accordion and dropdown.

Comment: try adding `.dropdown-menu {height:auto !important;max-height:auto!important}`

Comment: It didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Make the `z-index` a higher value.

```
.dropdown-menu {
  z-index: 50;
}
```

**UPDATE**

make your panel's `overflow` `visible`.

```
.panel .panel-default {
 overflow:visible;
}
```

Make sure that you add another custom class onto your panel otherwise this CSS will affect any panels on any page that this CSS is apart of.

Comment: @MariamAL-Kassar Then post your code as a snippet or use jsFiddle/codepen to re-create your page so we can see it for ourselves.

Comment: @MariamAL-Kassar I have updated my answer to target the `ul`. Try this and see if that works?

Comment: I updated my question and added the accordion code with dropdown ^_^

Comment: @MariamAL-Kassar I appreciate that, but that doesn't help because it's missing the CSS/JS and what ever else it needs to run. Either create a codepen/jsfiddle or turn your stackoverflow question into a snippet with CTRL+M in the edit mode. We need to actually see this physically running. We need enough code to re-create your page so we can debug it.

Comment: Ok I will make it :D

Comment: I am so sorry can you please see my update I am sorry I didn't make code on snippet  .. maybe my update can help..

Comment: Unless you make a snippet I can't help you

Comment: here my jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/p0cxsfbx/1/
 thank in advance :D

Comment: @MariamAL-Kassar Thank you. See your solution in the updated answer above.

Answer (score 1):

after our discussion in comment i understand that you have a problem when screen size is in small device `@media (max-width:992px){}`

so try adding this to your css :

```
 @media (max-width:992px){
.dropdown-menu{width:100% !important;right:0!important;}
}
```

Comment: try this `.dropdown-menu {
position: fixed;
top: auto;
left:auto;
min-width: 50px;right:5%}`

Comment: Ya I added right before but the problem with mobile if I open the website on the mobile or tablet the dropdown will appear in a wrong place

Comment: @MariamAL-Kassar, i have handled your small device problem with media-query see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "dropup" instead of "dropdown" class in the div containing the menu?

Please check below code hope it helps.

```html
<div class="dropup">   // <<<<changed here
<a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
   data-target="#">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>
  </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu download-dropdown pull-right" role="menu">
  <li role="presentation">
 <a href="#">Original data</a>
     </li>
   <li role="presentation">
 <a href="#">Original data</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```